# React Hook setState passed as prop is firing, but not actually changing the state

Tags: reactjs, try-catch, react-hooks

I am trying to set up a Login function for an app I am building and I am having trouble getting the 'user' object to update when I successfully login. What is strange is with 'console.log()' I know that the function is firing, and even shows the correct info passed into the function, but then state does not update. I know it isn't updating, because I made a button to change my 'isAuthenticated' status to 'true' and that works perfectly, and that same 'console.log()' shows the exact same info. I'm confident that it can work as a class, but I am really trying to make this a hooks only app to gain more practice. I'm sure I am breaking one of the rules of hooks, but am unsure how to fix it.

```
// App.js

function App() {

    const [auth, setAuth] = React.useState({
        isAuthenticated: false,
        user: null,  // Expects Cognito User Token
    });

    const setAuthStatus = authStatus => {
        setAuth({...auth, isAuthenticated: authStatus});
        console.log(authStatus, auth)
    };

    const setUser = user => {
        setAuth({...auth, user: user});
    };

    const authProps = {  // Wrapping for easy pass down
        isAuthenticated: auth.isAuthenticated,
        user: auth.user,
        setAuthStatus: setAuthStatus,
        setUser: setUser,
    };

return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <NavBar auth={authProps}/>
            <button onClick={() => authProps.setAuthStatus(!auth.isAuthenticated)}>Click</button>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path={"/"} component={LandingPage}/>
                <Route exact path={"/main"} render={(props) => <MainWindow {...props} auth={authProps}/>}/>
                <Route exact path={"/register"} render={(props) => <Register {...props} auth={authProps}/>}/>
                <Route exact path={"/register/success"} component={RegisterSuccess}/>
                <Route exact path={"/login"} render={(props) => <Login {...props} auth={authProps}/>}/>
                <Route exact path={"/logout"} render={(props) => <Logout {...props} auth={authProps}/>}/>
                <Route component={NotFound}/>
            </Switch>
            <Footer/>
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
}

export default App;
```

I wrapped up the functions and the state variables and passed them down. That button is a tester button, which works fine.

```
Login.jsx

function Login(props) {
    // styles stuff, and form validation thingies

    const handleSubmit = async event => {
        event.preventDefault();

        clearErrorState();
        try {
            const user = await Auth.signIn(values.username, values.password);
            props.auth.setAuthStatus(true);  // *** Fires, but no state change ***
            props.auth.setUser(user);
            props.history.push("/main")
        } catch (error) {  // Sometimes returned as error, or error.message
            let err = null;
            !error.message ? err = {"message": error} : err = error;  // Normalize
            setValues({
                ...values, errors: {cognito: err}
            });
        }
    };
```

I even made a sample button on the Login.jsx form and that was able to change the state with the exact same 'props.auth.setAuthStatus' function using the same lambda style that is in the App.js file.

I have been unable to find any examples or code that seems to run into the same issue. There are examples of setState inside try / catch blocks but none where you pass it from a parent.

- As an aside, I decided not to use Context or Redux for this App at this moment, but if I need one of them to make this work then please let me know and I'll gladly switch it up. I haven't used them, but its only because the App isn't going to be that big.

Comment: search/google why you can't expect updated value after `setState`... for hooks it works the same way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, figured it out and I hope this will help others. This is a specific hook issue and I am sad that it took me forever to solve.

If I had Redux Dev Tools up I would have solved this in five minutes.

I finally made a dummy button that showed me the State after Login and found my issue. Because I had made my 'auth' state have 'isAuth' and 'user' I was making two separate calls to change the state when I logged in. In a Class based React, each setState call just overwrites the value you are changing, however since Hooks requires you to copy the original state and then also change your value I was sending two state changes at the same time.

Due to the fun of how state changes asynchronously, the second setState call would grab the original state and put the Cognito user in, while still having the 'isAuth' equal to 'false' from the original state and then overwrite the first setState call that changed it to 'true'.

I fixed that by putting each state in its own state: [auth, setAuth] and [user, setUserToken] so each has its own separate call.

TLDR: When sending multiple 'setState' calls to the same state object using hooks, each 'setState' call might end up overwriting your other calls with old information. Split your states up if you need each to update in the same function.